# How to pass a data from Javascript to PHP Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

what I'm trying to do is a function in javascript that sends a simple data to a laravel controller and then upload it to the database, the problem I have is that until now I have not been able to find a way to send this data, always I get error 500.

Laravel Controller:

```
public function crearRegistro(Request $request){

$registro = new Registro();
$registro->indicador = $request->indicador;
$registro->save(); 
}
```

Javasript Function:

```
    $scope.calculoIndicador = function(){
  $http.post("/calculoIndicador")
  .then(function(response) {
    });
  $scope.indicador = 5 +5;
   alert('Se ha guardado correctamente');

}
```

view:

```
<input class="btn btn-success" style="" ng-click="calculoIndicador()" 
 type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/calculoIndicador', 'TecnologiaController@crearRegistro');
```

Comment: If you get 500 in ajax requests, you may not be able to see the stack trace in your browser, but you can still find the stack trace in the file `storage/logs/*.log` (the file name may vary.) What does the trace say when your 500 occurred? They come with timestamps, so it should be easy to spot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(First, sorry with my bad english)

I assume that you use Laravel 5.6. On controller you have to use: 
`$request->all()` method to get the data passed to controller via post on javascript. On your code i assume yout want the "indicador", so:

```
$requestData = $request->all();
$registro->indicador = $requestData['indicador'];
```

But on your javascript you have to pass "indicador" as parameter on post request data. So, on javascript (or typescript of Angular) post do something like this:

```
$http.post("/calculoIndicador", {indicador: 'your_data'}).then(
    function(response) {
      $scope.status = response.status;
      $scope.data = response.data;
    }, function(response) {
      $scope.data = response.data || 'Request failed';
      $scope.status = response.status;
    }
)
```

Can you update this page with stack trace of this error?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it helped me a lot